# How to realistically generate timestamp for mock events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, mocking, timestamp

I have a task for generating random mock events with timestamp.

Currently I am using `timestamp: Date.now()` to deal with it but I find it to be too fake. I wanted to generate events with timestamps that are relatively recent and also randomized.

Could you guys suggest some ways of doing that?

Comment: `Date.now() - Math.random() * interval`

Answer (score 2):

I would do `Date.now()-Math.random()*(upperThreshold-lowerThreshold)+lowerThreshold`